# emacs collapsing functions in class using outline-minor-mode

Tags: emacs, outline

What kind of a hook should i use to collapse just functions in the class. I want to see the outline of the functions in the class but if i hook hide-all everything including the class is collapsed during open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little snippet does the trick for me.  However, you probably want to restrict which files have outline mode enabled.  You can customize the commented out `when` statement to do that.  And add the proper close paren.

```
(defun my-outline-trigger ()
  "enable outline mode and hide all the function bodies"
  ;; (when (member major-mode '(cc-mode emacs-lisp-mode)) ....)
  (outline-minor-mode)
  (hide-body))

(add-hook 'find-file-hooks 'my-outline-trigger)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [hideshow.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow)  - it seems to work better for me.