# Emacs function collapsing

Tags: emacs

Is there some way to collapse Lisp functions in Emacs? I found these answers:

[emacs collapsing functions in class using outline-minor-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878766/emacs-collapsing-functions-in-class-using-outline-minor-mode)

[Is it possible to collapse a function in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156497/is-it-possible-to-collapse-a-function-in-emacs)

But they use add-hook, which gives me an "undefined function" error. What am I missing?

Comment: what is undefined? `hs-minor-mode` is autoloaded and installed by default in newer emacs versions and is designed to do this specifically. What version of emacs are you using?

Comment: GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-08-27

Comment: `C-h f` `hs-minor-mode`

Comment: The help suggests the keyboard shortcut C-c @ C-d (for example), but upon typing C-c @ I get the message "C-c @ is undefined".

Comment: maybe a windows problem? you can bind functions to whatever keys you want, or just call the function directly to try it out, eg `M-x hs-minor-mode`

Comment: You are reporting errors with things which should categorically not cause errors, which makes it very hard to assist.  Please *show* the failing configuration(s) in your question, so we can see exactly what code you are using.

Comment: Luckily, I figured it out, sidestepping the problem by just calling the function manually as jenesaisquoi suggested (less of a pain than figuring out where the issue is or reconfiguring stuff I don't understand).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [origami-mode](https://github.com/gregsexton/origami.el).

You can find detailed information about it in the Github page, but in short, just install it and call `origami-recursively-toggle-node` to fold and unfold a function.

There's no need for adding hooks or what not. You probably have something wrong with your config, possibly a require missing somewhere.

Comment: M-x install-package doesn't have the necessary packages.

Answer (score 0):

I use hs-minor-mode, as recommended in a comment by Rorschach in the question. The hs-minor-mode came with my emacs install and it works well.

To determine the useful commands, I typed Ctrl-h v hs-minor-mode-map and examined the keyboard map when hs-minor-mode is active (I added the comments so that the actual key sequences are easily read):

```lisp
 (3 keymap ; Ctrl-C
    (64 keymap ; @ (at-sign)
        (5 . hs-toggle-hiding) ; Ctrl-E
        (4 . hs-hide-block) ; Ctrl-D
        (20 . hs-hide-all) ; SPACE
        (1 . hs-show-all) ; Ctrl-A
        (3 . hs-toggle-hiding) ; Ctrl-C
        (12 . hs-hide-level) ; Ctrl-L
        (27 keymap ; ESC
            (19 . hs-show-all) ; Ctrl-S
            (8 . hs-hide-all)) ; Ctrl-H
        (19 . hs-show-block) ; Ctrl-S
        (8 . hs-hide-block)))) ; Ctrl-H
```

The recommended keystrokes are difficult to type. I decided to assign `Alt-H` to the following elisp (it's not exactly what I want yet, but I do like to assign one keystroke to do multiple things):

```lisp
(lambda () (interactive)
    (hs-minor-mode 1)
    (if (hs-find-block-beginning)
            (hs-toggle-hiding)
        (let ((from (point-min))
                (to (point-max)))
            (while (and
                (not (hs-overlay-at from))
                (setq from (next-overlay-change from))
                (not (= to from)))) ; locate first hs-overlay
            (if (= to from) ; hs-overlay-was-not-found
                (hs-hide-all)
                (hs-show-all))))))
```